# Freewheeling diode position

Tags: mosfet, diodes, body-diode

I have a pneumatic solenoid valve switching from IRF830 MOSFET. Solenoid valve connected to MOSFET by 2-3 feet long wire.

It's necessary to use a freewheeling diode for this?

What is the most suitable place to mount the diode ? Either near the solenoid valve or near MOSFET?

P.S.

This question about most suitable place for diode. Not about diode is need or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need the diode. It should be mounted reverse-bias *directly* across the solenoid coil if possible. This minimizes the current loop of the coil discharge path. Otherwise, in a position that places it closest to the coil.

Why is it helpful to minimize the current loop for the flyback diode? The spike that a large solenoid can generate is considerable. Even if it is suppressed on the origin controller, the field wiring loop is still carrying that high-energy current from the coil to the diode and back. This high-current transient can couple onto adjacent circuits, such as sensors and comms from other systems.

Mounting the diode on the coil does introduce a couple requirements: the coil lead needs to be polarized, and if there is field wiring involved, it needs to be checked with a voltmeter prior to powering up the controller. (One of my first jobs was with Honeywell, and I did exactly this for solenoid hookups as part of system bring-up. I fixed lots of electrician goofs.)

If ensuring wiring polarity is a problem, there is another solution: mount an R-C snubber across the coil like would be used for an AC supply. It’s not quite as effective as the diode, but it can work. (Maybe do that as well as the PCB-mounted diode.)

Comment: Thanks..What is the most suitable location? Near the solenoid or near the MOSFET?

Comment: Across the solenoid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes.  know it should be across the solenoid. But,
As I said in my question, solenoid located away from MOSFET. Solenoid connected using a 1m long wire. So, Can I place the diode either near the solenoid or near the MOSFET on PCB. What is the most suitable place? what is the reason for that?

Comment: Most often the diode will be mounted on the solenoid itself, then the wiring attached to it. The reason is as I said, to minimize the current loop for the discharge path. If this option isn’t available to you, mount the diode nearest the cable to the solenoid on the PCB.

Comment: Thanks... but, why Its beed to minimize  the current loop. Is there any advantage from that?

Comment: The diode will suppress the spike better, and less noise will get kicked back into the rest of your system.

Comment: Thanks. Compleately clear.